# Special diacritic character in Hive

Tags: unicode, hive, hiveql, diacritics

In Hive, I meet a problem with special characters. For example, I have this table A when I do a SELECT:

```
| day        | street                | 
+ 2018-09-13 + 4 Avenue L□o Lagrange +
```

The street should be "4 Avenue Léo Lagrange".

If I do :

```
SELECT street from A WHERE street = '4 Avenue L□o Lagrange'
```

I have an empty table.

If I do :

```
SELECT street from A WHERE street = '4 Avenue Léo Lagrange'
```

I have also an empty table.

How can I do a correct query ?

Comment: Is it a _display_ issue i.e. your terminal does not use UTF8 (cf. `echo $LANG` for diagnostics) or a _data upload_ issue i.e. you have a file encoded with Win-1252 and did not translate it to UTF8 before loading to Hadoop (cf. `file my_data_file_on_Linux.csv` for diagnostics - check about `iconv` for translation)

Answer (score 0):

Re-create the table with opencsv serde as below and it should solve your problem. See my result below:

```
 CREATE TABLE A (day date, street string) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
  WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "separatorChar" = ",")
  STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Load your table from the csv with below:

```
load data local inpath '<local path to csv>/street.csv' into table A;
```

Result:

```
hive> select * from A;
OK
2018-09-13      4 Avenue Léo Lagrange

hive> SELECT street from A WHERE street = '4 Avenue Léo Lagrange';
OK
4 Avenue Léo Lagrange
```